# I am solving PALIN on spoj ,but I am getting NZEC error even though it is working on ideone

Tags: java, adhoc

**A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.**

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    class next{

 public static void main(String ags[])
 {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=in.nextInt();
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    String s = in.next();

    if(s.length()%2==0)
    {

    int p = s.length()/2;
    String sub = s.substring(0,p);
    String sub2= s.substring(p,s.length());

    String reverse = new StringBuffer(sub).reverse().toString();

    int t = Integer.parseInt(reverse);
    int t1= Integer.parseInt(sub2);

        if(t>t1)
        {

            System.out.println(sub+reverse);

        }
        else
        {

            int t2 = Integer.parseInt(sub)+1;
            String s2 = Integer.toString(t2);
            String rev = new StringBuffer(s2).reverse().toString();
            System.out.println(s2+rev);

        }

    }
    else
    {

        int len = s.length()/2;
        String se1 = s.substring(0,len);
        String se2 = s.substring(len+1,s.length());

        String reverse = new StringBuffer(se1).reverse().toString();

        int t = Integer.parseInt(reverse);
        int t1= Integer.parseInt(se2);



            if(t>t1)
            {
                String se = s.substring(0,len+1);
                System.out.println(se+reverse);

            }
            else
            {
                String temp = s.substring(0,len+1);
                int tn = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                tn++;
                String left = Integer.toString(tn);
                String grip = left.substring(0,left.length()-1);
                String reve = new StringBuffer(grip).reverse().toString();
                    System.out.println(left+reve);

            }





    }

    }

   }

  }
```

**I am a beginner to programming.I am trying to solve this question #PALIN on spoj , but I am getting runtime error even though it is working on ideone.please help me**

Comment: please describe the problem, try to add more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, but the biggest is that you're calling `Integer.parseInt` on strings that can represent values *far* outside the range of `int`. The instructions say that the input can be up to a million digits, which means that you're calling `Integer.parseInt` on strings of up to half a million digits — meaning, strings of up to 10<sup>500000</sup>−1 — but `int`s only go up to 2<sup>31</sup>−1, which is less than 10<sup>10</sup>.

Once you've fixed that, you can test your code by doing the following:

- Factor out the logic that actually computes the result into its own method, with a signature like `String computeNextPalindrome(String s)`. That way, you can test that method by programmatically calling it and examining its result, rather than messing around with standard output.
- Write a method that initializes `expectedResult` to the expected result of `computeNextPalindrome("99999")` (namely `"100001"`) and then iterates downward from `99999` to `1`, verifying that `computeNextPalindrome` always returns `expectedResult`. After each verification, check if the current number is a palindrome, and if so, update `expectedResult` to the current number.

That way, you can exhaustively test that your logic is correct for all numbers up to five digits. Aside from the bug I mentioned above, about trying to use `int` for values well outside the range of `int`, *most* bugs will show up for some small cases. It's rather unusual to have a bug that only affects large values; so by exhaustively testing small values, you can find almost all bugs.

You can then check for bugs specific to large values by spot-testing a few large values, like `"1234567890123456789012345678901234568790"` (which should give `"1234567890123456789119876543210987654321"`).